# How to horizontally align Highcharter objects in Distill article in R Markdown?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-markdown, r-highcharter

How would you align multiple highcharter objects next to each other in a Distill Website in R Markdown? I have been trying

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: distill::distill_article
---

```{r, message = FALSE, echo = TRUE}
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
data(diamonds, economics_long, mpg, package = "ggplot2")
economics_long2 <- economics_long %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("pop", "uempmed"))
economics_long3 <- economics_long %>%
  filter(variable %in% c("pop", "unemploy"))

hw_grid(
  hchart(economics_long2, "line", hcaes(x = date, y = value01, group = variable)),
  hchart(economics_long3, "line", hcaes(x = date, y = value01, group = variable)),
  ncol = 2
)
```
````

In a standard HTML output, i.e. for `output: html_document` this code works well. However, for Distill articles, the two highcharter objects will not be printed next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

so far, just adding `fig.show='hold'` to the chunk still shows them stacked, but more spread out. you might have some luck implementing some HTML into the Rmarkdown for the alignment, I tried using `out.width="50%"` as a chunk argument, but no luck